# ViewPager without swipe and pass the swipe to parent TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i have nested `ViewPager` in my `Fragment`. and want to manually switch the `Fragment` inside the `ViewPager`. I managed to do this successfully.

I disable the swipe by doing it like this.

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
        return false;
    }
}
```

the problem is when i do it like this. i also disable the swipe of the parent tabs.

any idea?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this should cause the external viewPager to be disabled also, unless - you are using NonSwipeableViewPager  for both pagers.

Comment: i use 'NonSwipeableViewPager' inside fragment that is the content of one of the tabs. and outside i have tabs that you can swipe between.

Comment: did you check that without this custom viewPager the tabs are swipables?

Comment: yep. when i use the viewPager from the support library it's swipe inside the pager and the when it's reach the end. It's swiping the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Remove overrides for `onInterceptTouchEvent()` and `onTouchEvent()` and use this instead:

```
@Override
public boolean canScrollHorizontally(int direction) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a ViewFlipper with `autoStart` set to `false`?

You can have each fragment nested to it an switch the viewed fragment with `setDisplayedChild(child#)`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper